# Exception as FaultContract in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to create a robust way to pass exceptions from the server to the client but I seem to be missing something.

The intention is to use `FaultException` to wrap actual serializable `Exception` subclasses caught on the server side, pass them over WCF, then rethrow them at the client side.

Server side code:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyException))]
[ServiceContract]
interface IContract
{
    [FaultContract(typeof(MyException))]
    [OperationContract]
    void Foo();
}

class Service : IContract
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        try
        {
            Bar();
        }
        catch (MyException ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException<MyException>(ex, ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Client side code:

```
try
{
    client.Foo();
}
catch (FaultException<MyException> ex)
{
    throw ex.Detail;
}
catch (FaultException ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

`MyException`:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class MyException: Exception
{
    public MyException(string description)
        : base(description)
    {
    }

    public MyException()
    {
    }

    public MyException(string message, Exception innerException) 
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    private MyException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```

What I'm observing is that the server side code executes the `catch (MyException ex)` block but when the fault gets back to the client side, the code goes into the `catch (FaultException ex)` block and rethrows a normal `FaultException`, rather than `MyException` (interestingly, the `FaultException` does contain the message of the original `MyException` object).

Note that both the client and server have visibility of `MyException`, svcutil generates the correct attributes for the client side service contract and the WCF logs don't show any serialization errors.

Comment: What happens if you put a `catch(MyException ex)` on the client side? Also can you show the code for `MyException`?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: catching `MyException` didn't change anything, the actual type caught by the client code is untyped `FaultException`. Code for `MyException` posted.

Comment: Try the [Generic variation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199(v=vs.110).aspx) of FaultException. It lets you set some detail object. But you'd still be catching a FaultException<T>.

Comment: @musaul: Unless I'm missing something, that's exactly what I'm doing in the code posted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717231/faultexception-and-custom-exception-wcf But I don't want to vote to close because I have single vote close power on C# tagged questions and I am not confident enough to be the only person who says this is a duplicate. (In summary of the duplicate, even though your exception is marked Seriaizeable you still need a `DataContract` attribute on it)

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: Ugh, that seems to be the case here as well. Problem is, as someone else commented there, marking `MyException` as both `[Serializable]` and `[DataContract]` produces a compilation error.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: Also, I'd understand the need for `[DataContract]` if `MyException` was only known to the server side, but in my case both the client and the server build against and assembly that contains the exception.